# Jquery post call back not works

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, json

Hi my jQuery callback function does not work.

```
 Competitor = {
    addCompetitorForSave: function($data) {

            $.post('/competition/add', $data , function($json) {

            }, 'json');

           return $json; // I need to return json data .
        }
}
```

after this I need to do  next .

```
 var data  = $('someForm').serialize();
 var $json  = Competition.addCompetitorForSave(data);
```

Thanks  a lot.

Comment: You need to wait for the result before you can do anything with it.

Comment: That's not gonna work out well. You need to rethink your design :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `post` completes asynchronously but the `alert` runs synchronously.  Hence the `qa` value hasn't been set yet.  Instead of return a value here you need to pass an additional callback into `addCompetitorForSave`.

```
addCompetitorForSave: function($data, callback) {
  var qa  = 0;
  $.post('/competition/add', $data , function($json) {
    callback($json);
  }, 'json');
}

var obj = ...;
obj.addCompetitorForSave(theData, function(qa) {
  alert(qa);
});
```

Answer (score 3):

The alert is called before the post has had a chance to complete. Put the alert inside the callback.

Comment: Returning qa doesn't make sense though since the callback won't be invoked before addCompetitorForSave returns.

Comment: I know, I was just giving a nudge in the right direction to understand the problem ;)

Comment: absolutely - I was adding a bit more nudging to the OP :)

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
addCompetitorForSave: function($data) {

        var qa  = 0;


        $.post('/competition/add', $data , function($json) {
             qa = $json; //this does not work
             alert(qa); //getting 0;
        }, 'json');

        return qa;
    }
```